# Как на Python записать массив в файл?

Tags: php, python

На PHP пишу так, все работает без проблем:

```
  file_put_contents($file, implode("\n",$data)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Переписал скрипт на Python, в файл при этом записывается совсем не то что нужно:

```
f = open(file, 'w+')
f.write("\n".join(data))
f.close()
```

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Не то, что нужно, а что именно?

Comment: Как минимум в Python нет массивов

Comment: @Дмитрий, повторите еще раз, что вы сказали?)

Comment: @Let's say Pie, насколько я помню, там называется это дело не массив, а список

Comment: @Дмитрий какая разница как называется

Comment: @Эникейщик, так можно говорить тогда про что угодно "какая разница, что у него записывается, главное что записывается"

Comment: добавьте код с описанием того что в  `data`
 а то в "пыхе" небось словарь сидит?
а что в питоне?

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets в "пыхе" массивы это словари, так-то. Если явно не указывать ключ, то он будет числовым, т.е. индексом.

Comment: @KeterDev так я про то и гутарю, что хотелось бы понять что там записывается. А то окажется, что нужна сериализация

Answer (score 1):

Списки удобнее сохранять с помощью json.

Запись в файл:

```
import json

# список для записи, но с помощью json можно записывать любые объекты
lst = [0, 1, 2]

# открываем файл в режиме записи (обязательно)
# файл не нужно закрывать если используется с `with`
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fw:
    # записываем
    json.dump(lst, fw)
```

Чтение из файла:

```
import json

# открываем файл в режиме чтения
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr:
    # читаем из файла
    lst = json.load(fr)
```

Comment: Если Python 3, то можно использовать менеджер контекста `with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:`, тогда не нужно контролировать закрытие файла.

Comment: Разницы никакой, в принципе, просто поток закрывается потом сам. Хорошо, я добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перевести в массив [] '\n'.join(list(data))

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).