# Можно ли создать систему сохранения в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли создать систему сохранения в Python, если можно то как?

Допустим(на примере бота симулятора):Пользователь вводит "save" и все переменные записываются в какой нибудь файл, и когда пишет "load", перезайдя в приложение, те данные восстанавливаются

(Если сказать легче, то:
Изначально переменная была 5000. Пользователь изменил ее до 50000(инпутом). Как сохранить это значение в какой нибудь файл функцией "save", и восстановить при следующем заходе функцией "load")

Comment: прямой ответ: «да», уже множество множество "систем сохранения" существует (к примеру: postgres, redis, clickhouse, просто диск в каком-нибудь формате, и много другого — что выбрать зависит от задачи). Вопрос слишком обширный, если содержательно отвечать

Comment: Да, всё можно сделать даже в точности так, как вы описали. Про ввод и про чтения-сохранения файла рассказывается в любом учебнике по питону

Answer (score 1):

если вы действительно хотите сохранять переменные, а не их значения в файле, используйте модуль для сериализации. Пример вот [отсюда](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-pickle.html):

```
import pickle
data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
    'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
    'c': {None, True, False}
}
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = pickle.load(f)
print(data_new)
```

выведет:

```
{'c': {False, True, None}, 'a': [1, 2.0, 3, (4+6j)], 'b': ('character string', b'byte string')}
```

Здесь для примера `data` был - словарь, но могло быть что угодно. Хоть список, файл или одна буква.

Ту же задачу выполняет модуль JSON. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893768/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB) есть пример как сделать сохранение и загрузку при помощи этого модуля. Все делается по сути идентично, однако `pickle` может сохранять все пайтоновские объекты (кроме классов) и более компактен, зато JSON легче читается в файле и легко переводится в JSON...

Comment: "Сам не знаю и не видел, но сосед рассказывал..." (с) в общем, где-то в какой-то статейке я натыкался краем глаза на утверждение, что не всё и не всегда `pickle` корректно сериализирует, поэтому, пожалуйста, ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО ознакомьтесь с документацией модуля прежде чем пускать код в production. Лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть.

Comment: @КапитанФлинт - видимо речь идет о классах и пользовательских объектах. Не встречал. пороюсь, спасибки

Comment: возможно. к сожалению, уже не припомню, давненько дело было. а мой комментарий был адресован скорее автору вопроса, поскольку Ваша компетентность сомнений не вызывает и в подобных советах Вы явно не нуждаетесь :) судя по профилю